# Bootstrap 4, one of the nav-items in my navbar-collapse class not changing background color when it's active

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I'm trying to change the background color of an active item in my dropdown menu.
So what I'm targetting is the aisles nav-item, which has a dropdown for 8 different categories. So for example, when I'm on Fruits and Vegetables, I would like for a color surrounding that category to be fixed on it so that it indicates to the users that it's on that category.
Right now, Bootstrap 4 applies a blue background color, but I want to change it to match my website.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-fill w-100" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="allproducts.html">All Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="summer.html">Summer Essentials</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="sale.html">SALE</a>
      </li>

     <li class="nav-item active dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data- 
         toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Aisles
        </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" style="background-color: 
      #FF6347";>
        <a class= "dropdown-item active" href="aisle1.html"><span>Fruits & Vegetables</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle2.html"><span>Dairy & Eggs</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle3.html"><span>Meat & Poultry</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle4.html"><span>Snacks</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle5.html"><span>Bread & Bakery</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle6.html"><span>Beverages</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle7.html"><span>Cleaning & Household</span></a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="aisle8.html"><span>Beauty</span></a>
      </div>
   </li>



</div>
```

Can you please help me achieve this, thanks.

Comment: You need to show us the CSS with which you are trying to accomplish this...[reprex].